# Jenkins scripted pipeline doesn't return all causes for parallel build job failures

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a simple scripted pipeline as follows -

```
import hudson.model.*
import groovy.json.*

def map = [:]
map['second'] = {
    build job: "childPipeline1", propagate: true, wait: true
}

map['third'] = {
    build job: "childPipeline2", propagate: true, wait: true
}

try {    
    parallel map   
}catch(Exception e) {
    e.getCauses().each {
        echo "${it.getShortDescription()}"
     }
}
```

Actual map creation code is dynamic and looks something like this -

```
map["${substage}_${subdir}"] = {build job: "ci_pipeline_${substage}${jobSuffix}", parameters: downstreamParams[subdir], propagate: true}
```

When I execute this, I expect that stages 2 and 3 will fail (simulated) and when I catch the Exception, I get a `org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.FlowInterruptedException` with ***just one*** cause element in the cause list -

```
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] parallel
[Pipeline] { (Branch: second)
[Pipeline] { (Branch: third)
[Pipeline] build (Building childPipeline1)
Scheduling project: childPipeline1
[Pipeline] build (Building childPipeline2)
Scheduling project: childPipeline2
Starting building: childPipeline1 #1333
Starting building: childPipeline2 #148
[Pipeline] }
Failed in branch third
[Pipeline] }
Failed in branch second
[Pipeline] // parallel
[Pipeline] echo
childPipeline2 #148 completed with status FAILURE (propagate: false to ignore)
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

However, when I throw the exception i.e., `throw e`, I can see all the failure parallel jobs in the Jenkins web console log as below -

```
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] parallel
[Pipeline] { (Branch: second)
[Pipeline] { (Branch: third)
[Pipeline] build (Building childPipeline1)
Scheduling project: childPipeline1
[Pipeline] build (Building childPipeline2)
Scheduling project: childPipeline2
Starting building: childPipeline1 #1296
Starting building: childPipeline2 #126
[Pipeline] }
Failed in branch third
[Pipeline] }
Failed in branch second
[Pipeline] // parallel
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
childPipeline2 #126 completed with status FAILURE (propagate: false to ignore)
childPipeline1 #1296 completed with status FAILURE (propagate: false to ignore)
Finished: FAILURE
```

I am trying to get the result -

> childPipeline2 #126 completed with status FAILURE (propagate: false to ignore)
>
> childPipeline1 #1296 completed with status FAILURE (propagate: false to ignore)

and extract just the failed pipeline(s) name and the respective build numbers e.g., `childPipeline1: 126` and `childPipeline2: 1296`
***as in the Jenkins web console log*** (*i.e., with all causes; 2 in this example*) into a variable in my scripted pipeline.

Please help/guide me with this.

TIA.

Dynamic parallel map runner impl (based on @Yuri G's answer) is as follows -

```
map["${substage}_${subdir}"] = { try { build job: "ci_pipeline_${substage}${jobSuffix}", parameters: downstreamParams[subdir], propagate: true }catch(Exception e) { e.getCauses().each {echo "${it.getShortDescription()}"}}
```

Comment: Seems like you expect to get one exception with two causes. In fact you get two different exceptions. Your `catch` block processes only the first of them.

Comment: How can I catch both (all) exceptions ?

Comment: The object `e` is different for 2 different exceptions. If you need to collect both the exceptions, create a list outside the try-catch and add `cause` to the list from each exceptions. ` def causes = [] try {} catch(Exception e){causes.add(e.causes())} causes.each()...`

Comment: I just have one exception being thrown at the moment...I need to figure out where I can get **all**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can catch the error in every branch of parallel execution:

```
import hudson.model.*
import groovy.json.*

def map = [:]
map['second'] = {
  try {
    build job: "childPipeline1", propagate: true, wait: true    
  }catch(Exception e) {
    e.getCauses().each {
      echo "${it.getShortDescription()}"
    }
    throw e
  }

}

map['third'] = {
  try{
    build job: "childPipeline2", propagate: true, wait: true
  }catch(Exception e) {
     e.getCauses().each {
       echo "${it.getShortDescription()}"
     }
  throw e
  }
}

try {    
  parallel map   
}catch(Exception e) {
  e.getCauses().each {
    echo "${it.getShortDescription()}"
  }
}
```

Comment: I can't do that because my map is dynamically built. I will be passing only name of the job I want to build via `build job: "my-pipelinejob1-name"`

Comment: you can also wrap a `build` step with a function that will get a job name as a parameter

Comment: Here is how my actual map creation code looks like `map["${substage}_${subdir}"] = {build job: "ci_pipeline_${substage}${jobSuffix}", parameters: downstreamParams[subdir], propagate: true}`. Any ideas how I can catch an exception for each of the jobs here ?

Comment: I have updated OP with dynamic map creation info too...

Comment: If you can update your answer with dynamic code try-catch blocks I can accept it. Thanks so much !!!